# CiviVolunteer front-end assignment listing

Tags: civivolunteer

Does CiviVolunteer provide the capability for front-end users to see a volunteer listing of assigned volunteer slots for an event?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by front-end user you mean that the user doesn't have the "Access CiviCRM" permission?

Options for viewing the roster are outlined in the still-nascent [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/volunteer/en/latest/assignments/#roster). Summary:

- Using the admin menu, go to Volunteers > Manage Volunteer Projects (on Drupal the URL looks something like  https://example.org/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/manage). Note: this screen does not require "Access CiviCRM."
- Find the Project of interest, and click "View Volunteer Roster."

Comment: I meant an anonymous or authenticated user (WP). They could be logged in, but don't want them in Civi directly.  Was hoping to do through Profile listing?  (Would also like them to be able to change their assignment if possible through like-wise interface !?!?)

Comment: For most users of CiviVolunteer it would be a privacy problem to make the names of their volunteers (plus when and where you can meet them!) public information. Rosters are only available to contacts who have permission to edit the details of the volunteer opportunity.

Comment: As for having volunteers change their assignments, CiviVolunteer per se doesn't provide that functionality. This might not be the best user experience, but you could configure the user dashboard (civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1) to display "Assigned Activities" (near the bottom of that screen). The users visiting their own dashboard (civicrm/user) would see the list of stuff assigned to them. With the appropriate permissions, they *may* be able to edit them.

Comment: Or if you need a more streamlined user experience, you could hire the maintainers of CiviVolunteer to develop it to your specification. (Disclosure: that's my company.)